# NSCombobox selected state is not removed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am using NSCombobox to render my elements saved in an array as drop down.

On a button click my array gets updated and the number of elements drops to 2 from 1 but selected one does not change.

Detail :

- 2 elements in array: HELLO and SWATI
- Selected Hello.
- Clicked button & array now contains only SWATI
- Combobox gets updated with only 1 item.
- Still, HELLO is shown as selected one even if the array
  is updated.

Can someone suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `stringValue` of the combo box to SWATI.

Comment: I set its value to @"". So simple but surprising couldn't find it easily